# What is causing the 500 Internal Server Error in the script?

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

I am scraping the contents of a website using PHP. There are about 250 URLs. Sometimes, I will encounter a Captcha after one or two URLs and get the message about Captcha.

Other times, the script keeps running for quite some time. I receive a 500 error after that. I have no way to know if something went wrong on my end or the website I am scraping gave a 500 error.

Here is the order in which I load the files.

The file `get-data.php` contains following code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Some PHP code that does not output HTML

require_once(__DIR__."/header.php");

// Other PHP code that is supposed to output HTML upon scraping the content
```

The file `header.php` contains following code:

```
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
ini_set('implicit_flush', true);

// Some PHP code that does not output HTML

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

require_once('functions.php');
```

When I run `get-data.php`, it sets a bunch of options at the top and then runs the PHP code. It includes the file `header.php` at a later stage. This `header.php` then sets a bunch of options and runs other PHP code.

I don't see any output on the screen even after setting options like `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('implicit_flush', true);`.

I don't make any changes to the script on my end. The same script shows 500 server error or information about scraped pages like the data I need, "Captcha Encountered" or "404 Error".

Here is the pseudo-code for the output of information:

```
$urls = ['array', 'full', 'of', 'urls', 'to', 'be', 'scraped'];

foreach($urls as $url) {
   $page_html = get_page_contents_with_curl($url);

   if($page_html) {
       // Determine if it is a Captcha page
       if($captcha_page) {
         echo 'This is a Captcha page';
         break;
       } else {
         // Extract Data if it is not a Captcha Page
         echo 'Output the Data';
       }
   } else {
       if($page_gave_404) {
         echo 'We encountered 404 error';
       } else {
         echo 'Page gave some other error';
       }
   }
}
```

I have a couple of questions about this issue to help me resolve it.

1. Is it important to always include things like `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` at the very top or can they be anywhere?
2. How can I be sure that the 500 Internal server error is from my website or not the one I am scraping?
3. Can the 500 error occur due to a timeout? I have already set `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` so why would I still get timeout on my website?
4. The script always runs for at least a couple of minutes before showing 500 error. If the scraping was successful for at least some of these pages, I should be able to see output because of

```
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
ini_set('implicit_flush', true);
```

However, the only thing printed out on the page is a `500 Internal Error`.

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the server error log, it should tell you there.

Comment: Thanks @Havenard. Do you mean the `error_log` file or something else? What should I be looking for in that file?

Comment: Yes, if you're using Apache as web server, you probably have it in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

Comment: @Havenard I am on shared host and there are directories like `tmp` and `logs` in my root folder but not `log`. I entered `logs`but there was no `httpd` folder there. However, there was an `error_log` file in the directory from which I am running this script. Is that the same thing?

Comment: I don't know. If it's a shared host everything will depend on how the host is set up. If it has CPanel you can probably see logs there.

Comment: Thanks Havenard :). The logs in cPanel don't show a 500 error for my scripts. So I am guessing the error occurs on the website I am scraping right?

Comment: The error log shows script errors, not HTTP errors. It won't say "500 Internal Error", it will say something like "script 'function.php' not found", or "Undefined variable: $captcha_page"

Comment: @ChrisRichardson Could you please point me to some resources about web scraping with PHP and `chrome-driver`? I have never used `chrome-driver` before but have heard that it is powerful. I just could not figure out how to get started.

Comment: here is the project that will provide you with all thhe controls needed to surf the internet, click, navigate, etc. http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/

Comment: here is the driver I use inside of mink for chrome-driver. you will also need to have a version of headless chrome installed https://gitlab.com/DMore/chrome-mink-driver

Comment: Thanks @ChrisRichardson :)